# http to https redirect not working via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have picked up the following `.htaccess` snippet from another thread but on the site it is being tested on, I get a `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` Error.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If it helps the site is hosted on 123-reg.co.uk.

I have tried multiple variations to redirect non-www to www and then http to https but the same error each time.

Comment: Not sure offhand, but / is sometimes a special case that you have to call out a special rule for).  Do attempts of non-/ URLs work (like an explicit www.foo.com/index.html?

Answer (score 0):

This one is working fine, ignore the later one.

```
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

[Ignore this ] How to force SSL with .htaccess (Simple based on port 80 means http) - redirect all request to 443 automatically

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Ref; https://www.siteground.com/kb/how-to-force-ssl-with-htaccess/

Comment: The www.domain.co.uk page isn’t working

www.domain.co.uk redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS